# Existance of solution for a simple complex equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

Does any $u \in \mathbb{C}$ exist such that:

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}}=1$$

If yes, give an example please.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I thought a little about that myself and I think it goes like this ($m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r,\phi\in\mathbb{R}$):

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}}=\frac{|r|e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)}}{\sqrt{e^{i(\pi+2\pi m)}(|r|e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)})^2}}=\frac{e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)}}{e^{i\frac{\pi+2\pi m}{2}}e^{i (\phi+2\pi n)}}=e^{-i\pi(\frac{1}{2}+ m)}$$

Since $(\frac{1}{2}+m)$ can never be an even integer, the above equation can never hold.

Answer (score 3):

No such solution can exist. Squaring both sides gives $$\frac{u^2}{-u^2}=1$$
which can only hold true if $1 = -1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on why one apparently can generally assume that $\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{-u^2}}$? Your solution is only true if that holds.

Comment: @bollty We have $a = b \implies a^2 = b^2$, so $(\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}})^2 = 1^2$ is implied by the statement, and this gives my equation without taking the square root of anything.

Comment: Same story, please elaborate on why one generally can assume $(\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}})^2=\frac{(u)^2}{(\sqrt{-u^2})^2}$. I think with complex numbers this step is not trivial.

Comment: $(\frac{z}{w})^2 = (\frac{z \bar{w}}{w \bar{w}})^2 = \frac{z^2 \bar{w}^2}{w^2 \bar{w}^2} = \frac{z^2}{w^2}$ for complex $z,w$

Comment: That would again ask for the verification of the $\left(\frac{z^2}{w^2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{{\bar w}^2}{{\bar w}^2}\right)=\frac{(z^2 {\bar w}^2)}{(w^2{\bar w}^2)}$, which works well in the exponential representation.

Comment: @bollty and if you were to do that I would recommend you read the first chapter of any book on complex analysis, which proves many of the simple verifications you are asking for such that instead of resorting to long, drawn out, and tedious calculations with cumbersome notation we can think about the actual underlying math.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed like this:

$$u = \sqrt{-u^2}$$

Squaring both sides:

$$u ^ 2 = - u ^2 $$

or $$1 = -1$$

which is contradiction. Hence, not possible.

Comment: Please note, your altering of the shape has the trivial solution $u=0$ which is not true for the initial equation.

Comment: Switching sides/cancellation/division by u is applicable only with $u \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}}\cdot\frac{u}{\sqrt{-u^2}}=1.1 \implies\frac{u^2}{-u^2}=1 \implies -1=1$$
Your equation only give the solution $1=-1$. So It is not a valid equation whether $u \in \mathbb{C}$ or not.